# Manipulating API data with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm just learning Vue.js for the first time along with APIs and having trouble displaying the data I parse correctly.

It pulls all the information in but when it does it displays the output for one and everything in that array together then then all the information for the second.

Here is the code:

```vue
<template>
  <div class="users">
    <h1> Users </h1>
    <p v-for="user in heroes">Hero Name: {{user.localized_name}}</p><p v-for="user in users">Hero: {{user.hero_id}} User Lane Role: {{user.lane_role}} Games Played: {{user.games}} Games Won: {{user.wins}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="deleteUser(user)">X</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'users',
  name: 'heroes',

  data() {
    return {
      newUser: {},
      users: [],
      newHero: {},
      heroes: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addUser: function(e) {
      this.users.push({
        name: this.newUser.lane_role,
        email: this.newUser.games,
        website: this.newUser.wins,
        heroid: this.newUser.hero_id,
        contacted: false
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    },

    deleteUser: function(user) {
      this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    this.$http.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/scenarios/laneRoles')
    .then(function(response) {
      this.users = response.data;
    });

    this.$http.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes')
    .then(function(response) {
      this.heroes = response.data;
    });
  },

  addHeroes: function(e) {
    this.users.push({
      name: this.newHero.localized_name,
      contacted: false
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  },

  deleteUser: function(user) {
    this.heroes.splice(this.heroes.indexOf(user), 1);
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

.contacted {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

</style>
```

***It currently displays like this:***

Hero Name: Dark Willow

Hero Name: Pangolier

Hero Name: Grimstroke

Hero: 1 User Lane Role: 1 Games Played: 1559 Games Won: 593

Hero: 1 User Lane Role: 2 Games Played: 1277 Games Won: 755

Hero: 1 User Lane Role: 3 Games Played: 403 Games Won: 95

***But I want it to display something like:***

Hero Name: Dark Willow User Lane Role: 1 Games Played: 1559 Games Won: 593

Hero Name: Pangolier User Lane Role: 2 Games Played: 1277 Games Won: 755

This is pulling data from two different APIs because in the first one it just has the hero ID and not the name. It may be better if I could somehow make a function to where if it parses a certain ID I replace it with the hero name.

For example: if {{user.hero_id}} == 1 display Dark Willow.

Comment: Do you have some way of joining the heroes from both data sets on an ID or name? Ideally both data sets should include the IDs of each hero (is that the case?).

Comment: Yes, both data sets have a hero ID. In the first API it's labeled with just "id" in the second set it's labeled under "hero_id"

Comment: Is there any difference between a "user" and a "hero"? Are they the same object but with different data?

Answer (score 0):

Nest 2 templates and use a lookup method to simulate a join.  Not sure of the relationship;  You may have to loop users first.  The point is you have access to both objects inside the inner template, before you have rendered any elements, and can't incorporate both in at the same time.

```
<div>
  <template v-for="hero in heroes">
    <template v-for="user in users(hero)">
      {{hero}} - {{user}}
    </template>
  </template>
</div>
```